# How to get the value which I sent via System.out.println?

Tags: java, system.out

Sorry I searched a lot but could not find an answer to it. If there is , I a apologize and please let me know.

If I have sent an value via `System.out.println` or `.print` is there any way to get it ? I mean after sending get all values sent via System.out and the last sent value ?

```
System.out.println("Hi");
String val = System.\\something
String last = System.\\something else
```

Thank you

Comment: String message = "Hi"; System.out.println(message); String last = message;

Comment: Thats not what I want. If value is sent by another function or something else which I cannot edit I cant get value. Sorry I knew that method but thats not what I want.And thats why i passed a literal not a variable

Comment: You want to dynamically get the history of all messages you sent to print ?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do this? There is probably another way to solve the problem.

Comment: You can replace `out` with your own `PrintStream` that holds onto the last value.

Comment: I guess if i understood your sentence correct yes. @Skeptor

Comment: you have to set the value of a variable in order to get a value.

Comment: By default, it is unlikely that you can get what was printed. On the other hand, `System.out` is just a `PrintStream`, meaning you can change it into, say, a decorated `PrintStream` that, besides printing (what it does already), it would store the values as well.

Comment: There had been some instance earlier to reduce little length or some other thing that I want the value @immibis

Comment: @DarshanJain ...what?

Comment: If i am printing something with a local variable inside a function I cant get all the values obviously.@immibis

Comment: @DarshanJain well then return the thing instead of, or as well as, printing it?

Comment: If there are multiple of multiple datatype and i am not allowed to use array ?. Moreover if i am using a class from java lib then how ? Thats the point @immibis

Comment: @DarshanJain You mean you have a library, that you're not allowed to modify, and the library prints stuff but doesn't return it or give you any way to access it?

Comment: I mean Java internal library . That contain classes like System (java.lang java.io) @immibis

Comment: @DarshanJain Which Java internal classes print stuff that you have no other way to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess below code will be useful for you :

Create a class and extend PrintStream

```
class StorePrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public static List<String> printList = new LinkedList<String>();

    public StorePrintStream(PrintStream org) {
        super(org);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String line) {
        printList.add(line);
        super.println(line);
    }

     public void println(int line) {
         this.println(String.valueOf(line));
     }

     // And so on for double etc..
}
```

Now use above class to track print information :

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setOut(new StorePrintStream(System.out));
        System.out.println("print line");
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        t2.meth1();
        System.out.println(StorePrintStream.printList);
      }
    }

class Test2 {
    public void meth1() {
        System.out.println("another print");
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I have to override all parameters ? Like for int double and different object ? Any way to do it quicker?

Comment: You have to take care of "print()", "printf()" and "println()" - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28long%29

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bit of a misunderstanding of what System.out.println does. System.out.println sends a String to the Outputstream (stdout) of the Java program. So it is returned to the operation system. That is generally used, to make an output visible to the user, but also to other applications. Another application could read that with System.in.read.

In your case you would like to use the output in the same application, which is unnecessary, because the application knows its own data.

If you need to store a history of the outputted data, you can certainly save the history in you own application - (as suggested in a comment) a decorated PrintStream could do the job.

If you are a Beginner with Java, it might be easier to write a new method that stores your history. Eg. you could add the following to your class:

```
private static LinkedList<String> stdoutHistory;

public static void betterPrintln(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
    stdoutHistory.add(s);
}

// this method returns the last printed output
public static String getLastOutput()
{
    return stdoutHistory.get(stdoutHistory.count()-1);
}
```

and then call that method, to print something

Comment: Wont `setOut` be better ?